# Leverage Browser Caching - failure

Tags: caching, browser

Pingdom.com test and Google Page Speed Insights give me the same Browser Leverage Cache failure.

I use this in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

# CSS

ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>
```

Though, If I check with Developer Network Tools in Chrome, I see the results I expect.

**Example:**

Google Test says that both files "jquery-ui.css" and "home.css" are set to expire in 60 minutes.

But, when I check using Chromes Developer Tools in the browser it displays that they expire in one month as they are supposed to.

Could there be a reason these tests can't read my site properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my server was using "mod_deflate" (Apache). This must have been tricking the testing sites.

What fixed it was changing my .htaccess calls to:

```
# mod_deflate
# 1 YEAR
ExpiresActive On
<FilesMatch "\.(otf|ico|pdf|flv)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 years"
Header unset Last-Modified
Header unset ETag
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>

# 1 MONTHS
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200, public"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>

# 30 MIN
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```